# Alternate page-up in vim?

Tags: vim, gvim

I just stumbled on <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to page-down in vim.  I'm wondering if there is something as useful (i.e. easier to reach than <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) for paging up.  I'm looking for something that is already there, not a custom mapping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PageDown and Shift-Down work the same as Ctrl-F, and PageUp and Shift-Up work the same as Ctrl-B. See

```
:help CTRL-F
:help CTRL-B
```

You can see all Vim's key bindings at

```
:help index
```

To see the help topics containing some keyword, type `:help` followed by the keyword, followed by Ctrl-D.

Comment: hrm, Shift-Enter is not mentioned at all in `:help index.`  Unfortunately, PageUp and Shift-Up are even less reachable than just CTRL-F and CTRL-B.  I was just hoping there was something as convenient as Shift-Enter for going up a page instead of down a page.  Kind of looking like there isn't.

Comment: I noticed that Shift-Enter and the equivalent <S-CR> were missing from the documentation, so I sent a note to the vim_user list to find out why. I agree that PageUp and PageDown aren't easy to use, but Ctrl-F, Ctrl-B, Ctrl-E, Ctrl-Y and the rest become easier after you use them for a while. I don't know of anything as easy as Shift-Enter, though.

Comment: While you answer isn't what I was hoping for, you have still answered my question.  Thanks for the efforts.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> will scroll the window down and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> up. It might be easier to reach as you avoid the right ctrl.

This is not the same as page-up/down but you can configure it to be using the 'scroll' option.

From the help (for ctrl+d):

> Scroll window Downwards in the buffer.  The number of
>   lines comes from the 'scroll' option (default: half a
>   screen).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>? It's the same that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> but in the other direction.

Comment: nope, was wondering if there was _another_ mapping (like shift+enter that I just happened to accidentally hit and like) that didn't include the right hand ctrl.

Comment: @digitaljoel: Ah, ok. No idea without mapping. I will leave the answer until found the correct one to avoid a similar misunderstood and I will delete this post after that. Good luck!